# Alternative to eval() for an array of bitwise operation on an array

Tags: php, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have an array that I want to use with the the bitwise *inclusive or* operation.

The two solutions at the moment are:

**A `foreach()` loop that evaluates them in order**

```
$final = 0;
foreach($bits as $bit)
  $final = $final | $bit;
}
```

**Imploding the array with the bitwise OR as the glue, and `eval()` the string**

```
eval(implode(' | ', $bits));
```

Are these the only options or am I missing a simple native array method?

Comment: Check if there is atleast one `1` in the array. If there is, then the output is `1`, else `0` :P

Comment: If the `$bits` are already exclusive, then [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) would do.

Comment: @HamZa, sorry, to clarify this is used before a following & check against another value, so I need more than a boolean response. Thanks

Comment: @mario Of course, thank you. array_sum with array_unique does it!

Comment: @Rhys I don't get your point. You have an array of `$bits`. If you `or` them all and if there is at least one `1`, then the outcome is obviously `1`.

Comment: @HamZa the resulting value is required for another bitwise operation afterwards, so I required a combination of the array's bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @mario's comment, the solution is:

```
array_sum(array_unique($bits));
```